# Windows .bat to print 1000+ PDF's only executes first line?

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file, adobe

I've created a `.bat` file similar to this:

```
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF1.pdf"
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF2.pdf"
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF3.pdf"
...
...
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF3000.pdf"
```

The goal is to print N PDF's while preserving the order set forth in the `.bat`.  The problem I keep running into is using this method (which is the only method capable of printing thousand's of PDF's whilst preserving order) only the first line is executed until adobe is closed manually.

I've tried prefacing each line with START CALL and I've tried delaying 5 seconds then TASKKILL AcroRd32.exe and all variations in between.  But I haven't had luck with the volume of PDF's I need to print and, of course, printing in the order in which they're specified in the `.bat`.

Comment: When I'm doing such jobs, I prefer use PDFCreator to create a single pdf and then print it. Notice that each call to AcroRd32 is asyncronous which means you can't be sure that processed commands are in correct sequence.

Comment: @LS_dev In my testing, this method preserves the order.  I agree a single PDF would be ideal but these PDF's are variable page counts, contain sensitive information, are mailed to separate customers, and our requirements are to print front and back.  A single PDF presents the risk of printing one customer's information on the back of another's print out.  Does PDFCreator have an SDK that would allow functionality to prevent the printing of one separate PDF onto the back of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be fairly simple and oddly enough I never found this suggested elsewhere.  I simply changed my `.bat` to this:

```
START AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF1.pdf"
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF2.pdf"
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF3.pdf"
...
...
AcroRd32.exe /n /h /t "\\filepath\SomePDF3000.pdf"
```

By prepending the first line with `START` I'm maintaining control within the current `.bat` and therefore the current window does not wait for the first command to terminate.